# position: fixed не работает в Google Chrome и Opera

Tags: css, position, fixed

Никак не могу позиционировать всплывающую подсказку ни в одном браузере, кроме FireFox.

Я пытаюсь стилизовать всплывающую подсказку - title с классом tooltip:

В html есть список с такими пунктами, как этот:

```
<li> 
    <a href='https://сайт.ru/страница.html' title='Специальный раздел'
    class='tooltip'> 
    <h3 class='title_block'>Раздел сайта</h3> 
</a> 
</li>
```

В css:

```
.tooltip:hover:after{
    bottom: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    right: 10%;

   position: fixed;
    padding: 5px 15px;

    z-index: 98;}
```

Я использую здесь position:fixed, чтобы моя подсказка отображалась при наведении в правом нижнем углу вьюпорта.

Так вот, у меня подсказка отображается в нужном месте только в Firefox.

В Chrome и Opera подсказка не позиционируется и отображается прямо под элементом, на который наводится курсор.

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить этот косяк. 
Спасибо!

Comment: не  title запишите а через data-title и будет кросбраузерно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например вот так...

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
}

a:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background: tomato;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<a href="" data-title="специальный раздед"> специальный раздел</a>
```

Comment: Всё получилось.Большое спасибо!!